# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh'

Tags: python, bokeh

I've tried changing PATHs, `pip install`, `pip env`. I don't know what else to try and it's getting frustrating.

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 
 % /usr/local/bin/python3 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 1, in <module>
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh'
(base) ~ %
```

I have both python2 and python3 installed.

Comment: So, I have python 2 and python 3 installed. I've read on the previous questions that it may be an issue with going to different paths, but haven't seen a specific answer as to how to fix this.

Comment: please update your question with more clarity on what cmds you are running and the full error trace that you get

Comment: You need to install bokeh first using pip.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. We encourage people to take some time and properly format questions. Moreover, try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61450397/edit) your post instead of adding relevant information in the comment section: they might get lost. This time I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be quite general. If it is related to set up a virtual environment you can do the following using venv in Linux.

```
# create and go to a project folder
$ mkdir project_folder
$ cd project_folder

# make a python virtual environment and activate
$ python -m venv ./venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate

# then pip install modules you need, for example numpy
(venv)$ pip install numpy

# check in a repl if you can import
(venv)$ python
>>>import numpy as np
>>>np.arange(1, 10, 2)
>>>

# to leave the virtual environment 
(venv)$ deactivate
$
```

See [Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). If you use Windows I recommend to use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) for installing packages and organize your Python environment.

If you want information on Bokeh there is a nice tuturial from Real Python [Interactive Data Visualization in Python With Bokeh](https://realpython.com/python-data-visualization-bokeh/).

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial and for the responses! Didn't work, but I will check the tutorials out.